# I am getting "module 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_datetimeIndex' "

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, attributeerror

I am getting “module '`pandas`' has no attribute '`to_datetimeIndex`' ”

Traceback:

```
File "c:\users\joshua lindsay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 324, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)

File "C:\Users\Joshua Lindsay\PycharmProjects\Python_project\StockWebApp.py", line 88, in <module>
    df = get_data(symbol, start, end)

File "C:\Users\Joshua Lindsay\PycharmProjects\Python_project\StockWebApp.py", line 80, in get_data
    df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetimeIndex(df['Date'].values))

File "c:\users\joshua lindsay\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 214, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("module 'pandas' has no attribute '{}'".format(name))
```

Comment: Use `get_data df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))`

Comment: thanks so much..now my application is working fine..

Answer (score 3):

`pandas` has nothing called `to_datetimeIndex` you can use `to_datetime` instead.

change this line:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetimeIndex(df['Date'].values))
```

To:

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))
```